# Create a media server for ps3 and pc

Tags: networking, wireless, server, multimedia, media

I have a second extra computer that I want to turn into a media server to house all my music and videos. I want to somehow have it on my network (wireless or wired) and have my ps3, pc, 360, and any other devices I allow to pull from it to play the files. Im not quite sure how to do this as im a bit new to linux still (though my current job is slowly helping) But im willing to learn if i can get some help doing this. Thank you in advance.

As well as any preferred linux version to use

Answer (score 1):

Just a few pointers here to get you started:

- if you don't need or want the second computer to use a monitor after the first installation steps, install Ubuntu Server and login from another computer using SSH (on Windows, use the PuTTY client). Otherwise, install Ubuntu Desktop. Version 14.04 LTS is the recommended "stable" version in both cases.
- Hook up a large disk drive to house all your content files and folders.
- Use Samba to turn the disk into a "share" - a location that can be accessed over the network from any networked computer. This is basically the Linux version of a Windows protocol, so most computers will recognize a share out of the box. Search this site for Samba-related questions.
- For specific questions, ask this forum.